# ClickHouse: How to delete on *AggregatingMergeTree tables from a materialized view

Tags: clickhouse

Having a structure where there is a `base` table, then a materialized view `base_mv` that aggregates sending the result `TO` an `AggregatedMergeTree` table `base_agg_by_id`. Then we have a view over this final table. `base_unique`. Similarly as in this blog post](https://www.altinity.com/blog/clickhouse-continues-to-crush-time-series).

However, if I delete from `base`, I would expect the `base_mv` would trigger the mutation and then act on it, and reflected on the `base_agg_by_id`, but it doesn't.

Is this the expected behaviour? How to `DELETE` in such a schema?

I've [seen here](https://github.com/yandex/ClickHouse/issues/2897) that in MVs that keep data you can act on `.inner` tables. However in this case, since the table is from an AggregatedMergeTree and its fields are defined as functions (e.g. `AggregateFunction(argMax, String, DateTime)` ), I cannot apply a deletion via a value such as `ALTER base_agg_by_id DELETE WHERE field = 'myval'`.

Note. For the record, we have these tables in a replicated environment using `Replicated*` engine: `base_d`, `base_agg_by_id_d`, `base_unique_d`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mutations are not propagated to materialized views.

The reason is very simple: it **not possible** in common case. And even in cases when it is theoretically possible it can be very expensive operation.

For example, let's say you're deleting one record from the table which references some `userid`. And your materialized view contains `uniqState( userid )`. Data structures used for calculating `uniqState` don't support 'remove' operation; but even if they would - the is no way to decide if that userid should be removed or not without rereading whole data for the partition again because that userid could be seen in other records too.

So in general case, you need to refill the whole partition for your AggregatedMergeTree.

I.e. something like (daily partitioning case):

```sql
    ALTER amt_table DROP PARTITION '2019-03-01';

    -- use same select as in your materialized view
    INSERT INTO amt_table SELECT ... WHERE date = '2019-03-01';
```